# Restricted file upload to remote the Ruby way

Tags: ruby, network-file-transfer, ssh

I am using a Rails web app on the machine `webapp`, from which I call an action, that pushes a file to a remote server `backend`. Due to security reasons, we are using SSH keys and put the public part into `user@backend:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. The keys are restricted, so the Rails app does not have full control over `user`, like this:

```
from="webapp",command="touch datafile; cat > datafile" ssh-rsa ...
```

The Ruby method looks like this

```
def self.push_file
  errors = `cat datafile | ssh -i id_rsa user@backend 'true' 2>&1`
  raise errors unless errors.empty?
end
```

What the Ruby code does is, it `cat`s the file and then connects to `backend` via SSH, where it executes the "command" `true`, which then executes the command specified in the `user@backend:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (create `datafile`, write content). Lastly, the `stdout` is overwritten by `stderr`, so I can notice errors, which may occurr.

The solution works (it might be noteworthy, that `datafile` is always <100KiB), but seems dirty in three ways:

- I am not using SCP for doing what is essentially a copy.

  - Possible fix: Find a way to restrict SCP to allow exactly this operation, nothing else
- I am using neither `Net::SSH` nor `Net::SCP`, but instead raw commands, the first is due to the need of pipes in order to execute the first command on `webapp` and the second one on `backend`; and the latter due to the non-restriction of SCP.
- `stdout` is overwritten by `stderr` in order to capture errors (least problematic, I know about `popen`)

Any suggestions on how to make the solution cleaner?

Comment: Have you looked at [Allow SCP but not actual login using SSH](http://serverfault.com/q/83856/15051)?

Comment: Good hint, but I could also just use the normal SCP then. The thing with SCP is, I cannot restrict access to certain files. The pubkey should _only_ have access to `user@backend:~/datafile` and nothing else. Using SCP, however, I could up/download whatever I like to/from anywhere `user` has access to on `backend`.

Comment: [Restricting an SSH/SCP/SFTP user to a directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9853/17535)

Comment: Thanks, sadly I am not administrating the machine, and currently we have for each Rails app a subdirectory in `user@backend:~` to call network scripts etc from, so I may not restrict `user` as a whole, since developers from other apps might need to use SFTP for their apps as well. Also I can't use `Match User user@webapp`, since there are multiple Rails apps on `webapp`. Either I'm missing something, or "cleaning the solution" is not doable for my case.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken but I really do not see why using `Net::SCP` would be any different (more dangerous) than copying by piping through `ssh`. It is not like by using `Net::SCP` you would be giving somebody more rights, it is all contained within your code and under your control.

If somebody tries to misuse `Net::SCP` he can also misuse the `cat` solution copying anything else the user `user` has access to.

But - AFAIK `2>&1` doesn’t really overwrite stdout by stderr, it appends stderr to stdout, in which case you would be raising an error also on output and not only on error.

Try this instead:

```
def self.push_file
    output = `cat datafile | (ssh -i id_rsa user@backend 'true' | sed 's/^/O: /' >&9 ) 9>&2 2>&1 | sed 's/^/E: /'`
    errors = output.select{|e|e.match(/^E:/)}.map{|e|e.sub(/^E: /, "")}
    raise errors unless errors.empty?
end
```

Found in [In the shell, what does “ 2>&1 ” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/693387)

If not using `SCP` you can still improve on this pipe solution by using `rsync` :

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i id_rsa" /home/user/datafile backend:/home/user/
```